# How to save image in external folder without overriding the last image taken

Tags: android-intent, android-camera

I have an app where i want to take pictures and save to an folder onn the phone/device.  The problem i am having is when i take the picture it saves it to that directory which works,  but when taking another photo it replaces the previous photo in that folder.  My question is how can i save the next photo without replacing previous photo?

Here is my code for the camere intent:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(Intent intent) {
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File cameraFolder;
if  (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new  File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"HikingImages/");
else
    cameraFolder= context.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();
String imageFileName = imagename;
photo = new File(cameraFolder, "HikingImages/" + imageFileName);
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a timestamp or an incrementing number to the filename

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

instead of:

```
 String imageFileName = imagename;
 photo = new File(cameraFolder, "HikingImages/" + imageFileName);
```

do this:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = imagename + "_" + timeStamp;
photo = new File(cameraFolder, "HikingImages/" + imageFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, but would it possible if you could show me how to do this?  or where do i need to put that in?

Comment: Okay, sorry have figured it out,  all i added was `String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";`